# undefined method `end_with?' for nil:NilClass but checking for nil first

Tags: ruby

I have a very simple method that checks if a string ends with one of a list of disallowed endings, the value might be nil or empty. I have a check for this, but i still keeps getting the error below, should my if not catch that case?
It is Ruby 1.9.

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `end_with?' for nil:NilClass
```

The Code

```
private
def self.validate_ending(value)
    disallowedEndings = [", the", ", a ", ", an", ", das", ", die", ", der", ", ein"]
    if value.nil? || value.empty?
        false
    end
    for s in disallowedEndings
        if value.end_with?(s)
            true
        end
    end
    false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `return false` would solve your problem (basically `return` is what ***makes*** code flow to stop and to return from method).
2. your indentation is awful :)
3. This is not how you declare a private class' singleton method.
4. Here is how your method might look like:

   ```
   DISALLOWED_ENDINGS = [", the", ", a ", ", an", ", das", ", die", ", der", ", ein"].freeze

   singleton_class.class_eval do
     private

     def validate_ending(value)
       return false if value.nil? || value.empty?
       return true  if DISALLOWED_ENDINGS.any? { |ending| value.end_with?(ending) }
       false
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: `return true` would also help

Comment: @CarlMarkham yep, was actually editing the answer :)

Comment: @Androme we've all been there

Comment: Thanks, especially for your example, it helped a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You need to `return false` after checking `value.nil? || value.empty?`. Simply stating `false` will not cause the method to return and the code below it will still be executed.

Comment: and your answer brings... what compared to the one already given? :)

Comment: Nothing. I had not yet seen your answer when I was writing this one. Your answer is indeed more complete.